# Email encryption reliability from SendGrid to Office365 with Optimistic TLS

Tags: email, ssl, encryption, office365, sendgrid

We are using the SendGrid API to send sensitive email to an Office365 hosted email address. Both services use opportunistic TLS by default, which would in turn make you believe that the email is always going to be encrypted with TLS.

What I'm trying to establish is this enough to assure a client that the TLS email encryption is guaranteed? or do we need to setup enforced TLS in SendGrid? (the con of the later is we then need a mechanism in place to check for emails that have been blocked in the very unlikely event TLS encryption could not be negotiated, which in turn is additional work for us).

Here is some of the information we have been looking at:

https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/Email_Infrastructure/does_sendgrid_support_end_to_end_tls.html

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/How-Exchange-Online-uses-TLS-to-secure-email-connections-in-Office-365-4cde0cda-3430-4dc0-b489-f2c0736c929f

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the Office365 server uses opportunistic TLS, and has a valid SSL certificate at all times (preferably issued by a certificate authority, not self signed), then the emails should always get delivered using a safe TLS connection.

If the Office365 server would have an issue at some point accepting TLS encrypted emails, then you should see a deferred event in your SendGrid account, and then the email will be delivered to the server with no encryption.

Cheers!